# Javascript get Object inside Object

Tags: javascript, json

I took a php array with double arguments (that has like ['contact']['en'] or ['contact']['fr'] or ['presentation']['en']) and did a json_encode to have its values in javascript (so I can use it for ajax)

when I do alert(JSON.stringify(myvariable, null, 4));
I get something like :

```
{
    "contact":{
        "fr":"value",
        "en":"value2",
        "es":"value3"
        },
    "presentation":{
        "fr":"value",
        "en":"value2"
        },
        etc...
}
```

What I want to do is to check if a value is equal to the first object (ex: contact=contact) then do a loop for that gets all the values when the condition is met. So if contact = contact, then get me the value of fr,en and es in contact.
I managed to do the first object with:

```
for (var k in variable){
    if(k ==  valuechecked)
        {

        }                           
    }
```

But when I do inside  if(k ==  valuechecked):

```
    for (var a in k){
        alert(a);
    }
```

It shows numbers from 0 up to I believe the amount of k there is (therefore the first object).
I managed to do what I want with php but not with javascript ... How do I get the values of the objects inside the validated object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be:

```
for (var a in variable[k]){
    alert(variable[k][a]);
}
```

`k` and `a` are strings (the *names* of the properties).

To avoid lots of repeated lookups, you'd probably save the object to a temp:

```
var entry = variable[k];
for (var a in entry){
    alert(entry[a]);
}
```

```js
var variable = {
  "contact":{
    "fr":"contactvalue",
    "en":"contactvalue2",
    "es":"contactvalue3"
  },
  "presentation":{
    "fr":"presentationvalue",
    "en":"presentationvalue2"
  },
};
var valuechecked = "contact";
for (var k in variable){
  if(k ==  valuechecked)
  {
    var entry = variable[k];
    for (var a in entry){
      snippet.log(entry[a]);
    }

  }                           
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Instead of `for-in` loops, another option (just to throw it out there) is:

```
Object.keys(variable).forEach(function(k) {
    if (k == valuechecked) {
        var entry = variable[k];
        Object.keys(entry).forEach(function(a) {
            // Use entry[a] here
        });
    }
});
```

```js
var variable = {
  "contact":{
    "fr":"contactvalue",
    "en":"contactvalue2",
    "es":"contactvalue3"
  },
  "presentation":{
    "fr":"presentationvalue",
    "en":"presentationvalue2"
  },
};
var valuechecked = "contact";
Object.keys(variable).forEach(function(k) {
  if (k == valuechecked) {
    var entry = variable[k];
    Object.keys(entry).forEach(function(a) {
      snippet.log(entry[a]);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

It's just handy because A) It only returns *own* properties, not inherited ones; and B) The iterator functions give you a nice contained scope for temps like `entry`. And if you do the same thing in other places, you can use named functions instead.

Note: `Object.keys` and `Array#forEach` are ES5 features present on all modern browsers. They can both be polyfilled on older browsers like IE8 if necessary.

Comment: nice and quick, I wanted to try it earlier but had a weird encoding bug! thanks!

Comment: tried it with the other option, strangely it doesn't work (at least with the alerts) even when I simply do: Object.keys(variable).forEach(function(k) { alert(variable[k])});

Comment: @user3595784: I've added live examples of both above. Both work, provided you're using a modern browser.

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {
"contact":{
    "fr":"value",
    "en":"value2",
    "es":"value3"
    },
"presentation":{
    "fr":"value",
    "en":"value2"
    }
}

for(var a in obj) { 
    if(a== 'contact') {
       var b = obj[a];
       console.log("b is",  b);
       for(var c in b) {
        console.log("c is", c);
       }
    }
 }
```

this is one way in which you can solve this

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for.
What you can do is this
First set the array as a far (which I'm sure you've done)

```
var array = {
"contact":{
    "fr":"value",
    "en":"value2",
    "es":"value3"
    },
"presentation":{
    "fr":"value",
    "en":"value2"
    },
    etc...
}
```

Here if contact exists. go through it.

```
for(first in array) {
    if (first == "contact") {
        // array.contact exists
        for(k in array.contact) {
             // k being key
             var thisValue = array.contact[k];
             console.log(thisValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this (see [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998044/javascript-get-object-inside-object/26998118#26998118)) but if you know that you're after a specific item in the object you can just ask for it directly rather than looking for a match first:

```js
//an example object:
    var myObject = {
        "contact":{
            "fr":"value",
            "en":"value2",
            "es":"value3"
            },
        "presentation":{
            "fr":"value",
            "en":"value2"
            }
    };
//get the part we are looking for:
    var obj = myObject["contact"];
//iterate over the object and alert each item:
    for (var item in obj){
        alert(item+" = "+obj[item]);
    }
```